# logging the response recieved from web services which can not be modified further

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have been using spring framework rest template to make call
to third party web service and getting the responseto which I 
am further logging as shown below

```java
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate
    .exchange(restApiUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
LOGGER.info("XML Response from AA :" + response.getBody());

System.out.println("XML Response from AA :"+ response.getBody());
```

Now when I scan my code against HP Fortify security vulnerabilities then it reports that data is written to an application or system log file that is Interpretation of the log files may be hindered or misdirected if an attacker can supply data to the application that is subsequently logged

so now please advise how can I log my data into logs that is the response and which can not be modified by attacker also

Answer (score 0):

Use [LOG4J](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) dependency to put Abstract logs and don't use Sysout for logs.

Comment: share the example please